# Call a method from another method at the same class in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i'm starting with Typescript and i'm with a problem to call one method from another method at the same class.

Reading about this problem some people said to use "this" before the method name, but, in my case it didn't work.

```
class PlaylistController {
  public async create(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    let artists = req.body.bands;
    artists = artists.split(',');

    const search = await Object.values(artists).map(
      (artistsName: string): void => this.searchArtists(artistsName),
    );

    return res.json(search);
  }

    private searchArtists = (artistName: string): void => {
      console.log(artistName);
    };

}
export default new PlaylistController();
```

Edit:
This is the code that i use to call my method:

```
class App {
  public express: express.Application;

  public constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
  }

  private middlewares(): void {
    this.express.use(express.json());
  }

  private routes(): void {
    this.express.get('/', (req, res): void => {
      res.send('API Rodando...');
    });

    this.express.post('/createPlaylist', PlaylistController.create);
  }
}

export default new App().express;
```

When i execute this code the method "searchArtists" is not called and i get the error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchArtists' of undefined.
(node:11941) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11941) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

So, i don't know what i'm doing wrong and i hope you can help me.

Comment: When you say you execute the code, is there more code you haven't posted here? As the code you have now alone will do nothing. Please post the code that calls the method if this is the case.

Comment: @Collierre thank you for the answer, i added the code that i use to call my methods.

Comment: And how are you importing `PlaylistController` into your second file?

Comment: @Collierre the import is ok, i use: import PlaylistController from './controllers/PlaylistController';

Comment: Hhm I'm not sure then. `this` should resolve to the `PlaylistController` instance within the `create` method. Perhaps the problem's something to do with the `this.express.post()` method, though I'm not familiar with Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed what looks like an unbound method `PlaylistController.create` at the second parameter to `this.express.post()`.   I assume the body of `post()` ends up actually calling the unbound method, your problem is that it has lost the original `this` context and you get that error.  [Passing around unbound methods is usually a mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Creating_a_bound_function):

```
const x = {
  a() { console.log("a"); },
  b() { this.a(); }
};
```

Here, `x` is an object with an `a` and a `b` method.  The `b` method calls `this.a()`.  If you call `b` directly as a method of `x`, everything works as you expect:

```
x.b(); // calling b as a property of x: "a"
```

But if you save the `x.b` method to a new variable (or pass it in a function parameter, etc):

```
const xb = x.b; // xb is the b method of x, but it is not bound to x any longer.
```

You can no longer call it directly:

```
try {
  xb(); // error at runtime: this is undefined
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); //  "TypeError, this is undefined"
}
```

The `xb()` call gives you a runtime error because when you call a function directly and not in the context of a property of some other object, the `this` context will be `undefined`.

Luckily this can be fixed by using the `bind()` method of the function object:

```
const xbBound = xb.bind(x); // explicitly bind the method to x again
xbBound(); // "a"
```

---

So, for your case, I would try rebinding the `PlaylistController.create` method to the `PlaylistController` object:

```
this.express.post('/createPlaylist', PlaylistController.create.bind(PlaylistController));
```

See if that works.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3gKBjAhgCgJSoyiQgA2ApgHSkgDmOARFg3gNwwC+ANBjAEb5CUABYBLCJVxtOaDqzRo4lAdID0qollKlRYWv2wRsMAA4AnECfJmoATxggAZvABcMJgwXFo8PknjK7Oq+MOIwIuQGALbkIiAAJg7OcFz8AK6woplGYCCwfCBpYIlQIPDYYPY0etaUClBm9uiYcCpBGtYWZtiwZkVQojFuImFhRfHkjrrk8bKaUMDCMDjkBM1E4BBkVDT0q+2YDAAqtlYAomZdqSNGY8WT0-GeHGjesK0AQoXF-q3KuvEcHA1B04CYdMAsqR7HwAeFhJEYnESmUEFhaFhdApPt9ASD3MwFMEbpRyGCzOQIBITCBoDgAOSqYAUrBQcgABVIWFsOmg9NSnO5vKgAGFwA0yBQzJRmeRWVRYcUcIKeeJReKLNprHg2EA)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your solution solved my problem. Also, I was able to understand well what was generating error in my code.